# keeping characters un-escaped in attributes when processing with XSLT

Tags: xslt, ivy

I'm transforming an ivy.xml file with XSLT, I basically want to update the `rev` attribute of a specific `dependency` tag. My problem is with the `conf` attribute, I want it to stay exactly the same, unfortunately `>` gets converted to `&gt;`. My ivy file looks like this:

```
<ivy-module version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">
    <info organisation="foo" module="libfoo" revision="1.0.1"/>
    <configurations>

    </configurations>
    <publications>
        <artifact name="libfoo" type="jar" conf="default" />
    </publications>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="easymock" name="easymock" rev="2.5.2" conf="test->default,class-extension"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

my XSL looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output />
    <xsl:param name="dependency.rev" />
    <xsl:param name="dependency.org" />
    <xsl:param name="dependency.name" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="dependency">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@name=$dependency.name">
                    <xsl:attribute name="rev">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$dependency.rev" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and my output looks like this:

```
<dependency org="easymock" name="easymock" rev="2.5.2" conf="test-&gt;default,class-extension"/>
```

I've tried setting `disable-output-escaping="no"` on an explicit set of the conf attribute, but that didn't work

```
<xsl:attribute name="conf">
    <xsl:value-of select="@conf" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</xsl:attribute>
```

Comment: What broken XML parser can't read the result properly?

Comment: There is nothing bad with the result you get. `test-&gt;` and `test->` both represent exactly the same string.

Comment: See my answer for explanation why you need not worry; also a simple proof that the "wrong" attribute value is actually exactly the same as the "good". :)

Comment: This file is used by a huge black hole of a system I have no control over. I'm trying to be cautious about what I present to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My problem is with the conf attribute,
>   I want it to stay exactly the same,
>   unfortunately `>` gets converted to
>   `&gt;`.

**You can't. As per the [W3 XSLT Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#section-XML-Output-Method)**:

"*It is an error for output escaping to be disabled for a text node that is used for something other than a text node in the result tree. Thus, it is an error to disable output escaping for an xsl:value-of or xsl:text element that is used to generate the string-value of a comment, processing instruction or attribute node*"

**There is nothing problematic in the `conf` attribute containing `test-&gt;`.**

In fact, both

```
conf="test->default,class-extension"
```

and

```
conf="test-&gt;default,class-extension"
```

have exactly the same string value.

**To verify this, just apply the following simple transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  "<xsl:value-of select="@conf"/>"
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**to the "bad" result**:

```
<dependency org="easymock"
            name="easymock"
            rev="2.5.2"
            conf="test-&gt;default,class-extension"
/>
```

**and what you get is**:

```
  "test->default,class-extension"
```

This is exactly the same as coding `&#160;` instead of `&nbsp;`  -- these are exactly the same characters, but specified in different ways.

Comment: Thanks Dimitre, so I guess if I want to do this I have to break the spec.

Comment: @airlust: This simply means: 1. You don't need at all to change the attribute; 2. No compliant XSLT processor would let you do this. BTW, at SO the established way of expressing gratitude is to accept the answer (by clicking on the green check-mark next to the answer).